# AngularJS - How do I update the URL query parameters using $location?

Tags: angularjs

I am need to add, update and remove query string parameters from the URL within one of my services. The trouble is the URL does not seem to update. I am trying the following:

```
var updateUrlParams = function (deepLinkEvent) {
  if (deepLinkEvent.title !== 'bookmarkTitle') {
    return;
  }
  var params = $location.search();
  if (deepLinkEvent.name === deepLinkEvents.removeFragment) {
    if (params[deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey]) {
      delete $location.$$search[deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey];
      $location.$$compose();
    }
  }
  if (deepLinkEvent.name === deepLinkEvents.setFragment) {
    $location.search(deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey, deepLinkEvent.fragmentValue);
    $location.$$compose();
  }

};
```

The above does not work. The URL is not updated when I try to remove a parameter key/value with:

```
 delete $location.$$search[deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey];
 $location.$$compose();
```

And the parameters are not updated or added with:

```
 $location.search(deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey, deepLinkEvent.fragmentValue);
 $location.$$compose();
```

Can someone show me the correct way to add/update and delete query parameters in the URL?

Thanks!

**Update**

This is also not working

```
//remove param
    $location(deepLinkEvent.fragmentKey, null);
```

Comment: Why not simply $location.url($location.path) ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `$location`, I use `$window` instead:

```
$window.location.href = "url"
```

I've never had any luck with `$location` myself, but `$window` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: That's not working either?! I'm even logging the url but the URL will not change in the browser. Weird.  $log.debug(url);
      $window.location.href = url;